# Compare 2 EditText entries and show errors on dialogs in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I'm trying to create a dialog with 2 edittexts for create a password. Here is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setTitle(title);
            alert.setMessage(message);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_pass, null);
            final EditText password = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.password);
            final EditText passconfirm = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.repeat_password);
            password.setMinEms(6);
            alert.setView(layout);
            alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    if (!password.getText().toString().equals(passconfirm.getText().toString())) {
                        passconfirm.setError(getString(R.string.password_mismatch));
                        return;
                    } else if (password.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        password.setError(getString(R.string.password_empty));
                        return;
                    } else {
                        secprefs.putString("master_password", password.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            alert.show();
```

The dialog is working fine and the password got stored if the 2 conditions are respected.
Now, if the 2 conditions are not met, the dialog close itself.
I would like to void dialog closing and show the little popup error. Anyone know why?

Another extra things i would like to set is the minimum lenght for the password. I tried with setMinEms(6) but it's not working.

Thanks

Comment: Just a query, where are you creating a dialog from the builder? Can you try `alert.create().show();`? For your second question try setting `android:minEms="` sets only the width of it. It has nothing to do with the minimum number of characters. Check that programatically.

Comment: dialog will be created in the onCreate methos. Also tried create.show but don't work :S.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is how i solved it for further related questions:

```
       AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.dlgtitle));
        alert.setMessage(getString(R.string.dlgmessage));
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pass_create, null);
        final EditText password = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.password);
        final EditText passconfirm = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.repeat_password);
        password.setMinEms(6);
        alert.setView(layout);
        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);
        alert.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                Button ok = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                if (ok != null) {
                    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (!password.getText().toString().equals(passconfirm.getText().toString())) {
                                password.setError(getString(R.string.password_mismatch));
                            } else if (password.getText().toString().length() <= 6) {
                                password.setError(getString(R.string.pass_lenght));
                            } else if (password.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                password.setError(getString(R.string.password_empty));
                            } else {
                                secprefs.putBoolean("first_step", false);
                                secprefs.putString("master_password", password.getText().toString());
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum length of the password can be checked by using a pattern like this ... example

```
password.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,}")
```

And about showing a message for error in the input you can use Toast like this example...

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Input error!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Hello, i was using the toast before trying to add the little error popup and yes, they was working but they also close the dialog! i would like to keep the dialog open!

Comment: you got now what you want??? you could Build a custom dialog with a 2 EditText with the attribute android:password="true", then manually set onClick listener the button, and explicitly choose what to do in it.

Comment: could you mark as an answer? need that for reputation score, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I was meaning it has solved for the extra things about the password lenght! the main questions was how to avoid dialog closing and showing the little error popup! i added the answer below and done the +1 on your answer for the extra thing!